# @Cacheable kills Hibernate Session?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've a problem since I switched from `@QueryHints` to `@Cacheable` on repository methods.

I have a Controller method annotated with Spring `@Transactional`, which calls a Service method (not annotated).
The service first gets an entity User with `repository.getByLogin(login)` and then loops on `parent.getChildren()`.

With `@Cacheable` on `getByLogin(login)`, I have a `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException` when trying to do `parent.getChildren()`

Controller (contains `@Transactional` which is a **bad practice**) :

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;    

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value="/add-son", method=POST)
    public void addSon(@RequestBody User son) {
        userService.addSon(son);
    }
}
```

Service:

```java
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo repository;

    public void addSon(User son) {
        User parent = repository.getByLogin(user.getParent()); // call to my repo
        for(User child: parent.getChildren()) { // breaks here
            System.out.println(child)
        }
        parent.addChild(son);
    }
}
```

My old Repository (worked):

```java
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @QueryHints({@QueryHint(name = COMMENT, value = "get user by login"),
                 @QueryHint(name = CACHEABLE, value = "true")})
    User findByLogin(String login);
}
```

My new Repository (seems to kill my hibernate session):

```java
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    @Cacheable(value = "myapp.entities.User", cacheManager = "springCacheManager", unless="#result == null")
    User findByLogin(String login);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```java
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: myapp.entities.User.children, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:545)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
        at myapp.services.UserService.addSon(UserService.java:19)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy194.addSon(Unknown Source)
        at myapp.controllers.UserController.addSon(UserController.java:20)
        at myapp.controllers.UserController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7053b110.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
        at myapp.controllers.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$66ec522b.addSon(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

Comment: LazyInitializedException is thrown when you are out of a transaction and trying to use the proxy to do CRUD. Therefore I think that spring is not configured to search controllers for @Transactional. Also make sure you have enabled caching: <cache:annotation-driven />. 
 
By the way: "I have a Controller annotated with @Transactional" .. don't do this! Bad architecture.

Comment: This is a bad architeture on this project, indeed :)
But it works well with `@QueryHints` in my repository, so the transaction is well propagated in the service (@Service bean).

Comment: Well `@Cacheable` and `@QueryHints` (for caching the query results!) are quite different beasts and serve quite a different purpose. You cannot simply put a hibernate managed object in a cache as that will also put it in a cache. Integrate second level caching on the hibernate level or figure out a way to reattach an object to a session (which might be dangerous because you are basically can run into issues sharing a single instance with multiple sessions!)>

Comment: @M.Deinum
Thank you, but I'm not sure to get it. Are you suggesting not to use `@Cacheable` ?
Because I'd like to do something like this: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable

Comment: Ofcource you could but with managed objects it isn't as easy as adding the annotation and configuration. If you are using hibernate I suggest configuring second level caching which integrates nicely with hibernate.

Comment: Did you find better solutions?

Comment: Sorry @FranXho, no solution so I finally haven't used `@Cacheable`

Answer (score 1):

When you use @Cacheable for entities your entity is added to the cache without lazy collection fetched. Lazy collection is loading when you access it but in that time session might be over and it is not possible to load lazy collection.
I would use service class in which repository is called and entities are transformed to transform objects (lazy collection loaded).
Then you will use transform objects and therefore you can annotate service method @Cacheable.